# Golang utf16le encoding for ldap password attribute

Tags: go, ldap

I'm trying to reset a MS Active Directory password attribute using ldap in Go. AD won't play nicely with `ldap.PasswordModifyRequest` so I'm using `ldap.NewModifyRequest`. (Using gopkg.in/ldap.v2)

AD will accept the password surrounded in quotes and utf16le encoded, in Python I can do this using

```
unicode_pass = unicode("\"secret\"", "iso-8859-1")
password_value = unicode_pass.encode("utf-16-le")
mod_attrs = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, "unicodePwd", [password_value])]
l.modify_s(user_dn, mod_attrs)
```

How can I do this in Go? Using `ldap.NewModifyRequest` and `Replace` I can change other attributes, but I need to pass `Request` `[]string` for the updated value, that needs to be my encoded password, and I'm running into type mismatches when I play around with `utf16.Encode`...

```
modify := ldap.NewModifyRequest(dn)
modify.Replace("unicodePwd", []string{"encodedsecret"})
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you provide the error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode) package to encode your string as UTF16.

Using this package you can write something like this:

```
utf16 := unicode.UTF16(unicode.LittleEndian, unicode.IgnoreBOM)

encoded, err := utf16.NewEncoder().String("encodedsecret")

modify := ldap.NewModifyRequest(dn)
modify.Replace("unicodePwd", []string{encoded})

// do something with modify
```